# Android: in-process broadcast

Tags: android

Android broadcast is a good IPC mechanism, but sometimes i only need broadcast or event notification within a process. I want to know if there's something like in-process broadcast?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), found in the Android Support package. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Local) demonstrating its use. Mostly it involves calling methods like `registerReceiver()` and `sendBroadcast()` on `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)` instead of directly on a `Context`.

Comment: @Todd: No, it is in the Android Support package. It should work back to Android 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/).  It's a publish subscribe library based on Google Guava, and made specifically for Android.